# Is there an efficient way to find the maximum so far in a pandas group?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a value 'risk' that (should) increase within each group. Each group is identified by 'id' and nested 'sub_id' values. I want to calculate the maximum value *so far* within a group's sequence - from 0-8 in this example. I'm using pandas `rolling` windowing operations, which has a fixed window size (pandas `expanding` has a similar constraint).

This sample works but seems very inefficient, especially when scaled up to many records and longer sequences. Does anyone have a better approach?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'id': ['a']*9 + ['b']*9,
        'sub_id':['x','x','x','y','y','y','z','z','z',
                  'q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q',
                 ],
        'seq': list(range(9)) + list(range(9)),
        'risk': [0.2 ,0.4, 0.3, 0.51, 0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.1, 0.8] + \
                [0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.21 ,0.15, 0.14, 0.3, 0.6, 0.1]
    }
)

df['rolling_max'] = df[['id','seq','risk']].groupby('id').rolling(2, on='seq').max().reset_index()['risk']
df['temp1'] = df[['risk','rolling_max']].max(axis=1)

# keep checking for max up to sequence size:
for i in range(2,9):
    c  = f'temp{i}'
    cc = f'temp{i-1}'
    df[c] = df[['id','seq',cc]].groupby('id').rolling(2, on='seq').max().reset_index()[cc]
    df[c] = df[[c,cc]].max(axis=1)
df['adjusted_risk'] = df[c]
df[['id','sub_id','seq','risk','adjusted_risk']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC your problem correctly you are looking for [cummax](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html) for each group.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'id': ['a']*9 + ['b']*9,
        'sub_id':['x','x','x','y','y','y','z','z','z',
                  'q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q',
                 ],
        'seq': list(range(9)) + list(range(9)),
        'risk': [0.2 ,0.4, 0.3, 0.51, 0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.1, 0.8] + \
                [0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.21 ,0.15, 0.14, 0.3, 0.6, 0.1]
    }
)
df['adjusted_risk'] = df.groupby('id')['risk'].cummax()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id sub_id  seq  risk  adjusted_risk
0   a      x    0  0.20           0.20
1   a      x    1  0.40           0.40
2   a      x    2  0.30           0.40
3   a      y    3  0.51           0.51
4   a      y    4  0.40           0.51
5   a      y    5  0.30           0.51
6   a      z    6  0.70           0.70
7   a      z    7  0.10           0.70
8   a      z    8  0.80           0.80
9   b      q    0  0.20           0.20
10  b      q    1  0.40           0.40
11  b      q    2  0.30           0.40
12  b      q    3  0.21           0.40
13  b      q    4  0.15           0.40
14  b      q    5  0.14           0.40
15  b      q    6  0.30           0.40
16  b      q    7  0.60           0.60
17  b      q    8  0.10           0.60
```